# Bug in Cognitive Service text to Speech (Raul, Apollo voice in Spanish)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm sending the following text in spanish: "Paciente  P2, Posición 6" to the voice "Raul, Apollo" but it seems that it's ignoring the accent of the word "Posición"

Answer (score 0):

The language of "es-MX, Raul, Apollo" is Spanish (Mexico), so I suggest you try using any of the Spanish (Spain) language voices like "es-ES, Pablo, Apollo" for example.

You can find the list of all the available voices, including their (locale, languages, gender, service name mapping) and the supported languages, including their (acoustic adaptation, language adaptation, pronunciation adaptation) in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/supported-languages)

Comment: I need an es-MX male voice and the only one available is that one. For some reason it isnt recognizing the tilde.

Comment: Can you confirm if that's a bug or I'm missing something?

Comment: You can try the voices through the demo page [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/) and try to customize the [SSML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup) to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ali, It seems that I will need to change the voice. If I write only the word "Posición", Raul voice works as expected, but with the complete frase it still ignores the tilde. Other voices read both cases correctly.